# How to get the desired character from the multiple underscored variable sized strings?

Tags: java, string

This is continuation of [How to get the desired character from the variable sized strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34450214/2018343)
but includes additional scenarios from which, a person names are to be extracted

```
 pot-1_Sam  [Sam is the word to be extracted]
 pot_444_Jack [Jack is the word to be extracted]
 pot_US-1_Sam  [Sam is the word to be extracted]
 pot_RUS_444_Jack[Jack is the word to be extracted]
 pot_UK_3_Nick_Samuel[Nick_Samuel is the word to be extracted]
 pot_8_James_Baldwin[James_Baldwin is the word to be extracted]
 pot_8_Jack_Furleng_Derik[Jack_Furleng_Derik is the word to be extracted]
```

Above are the Sample words from which the names person names are to be extracted. One thing to note is that The person name will always start after a "Number" and an "Underscore". How to achieve the above using Java?

Comment: Maybe you can use regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] strings = {
        "pot-1_Sam",
        "pot_444_Jack",
        "pot_US-1_Sam",
        "pot_RUS_444_Jack",
        "pot_UK_3_Nick_Samuel",
        "pot_8_James_Baldwin",
        "pot_8_Jack_Furleng_Derik"
};

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d_(\\w+)$");
for (String s : strings ){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regular expression:

```
^.*\d+_(.*)$
```

... and extract the value of the 1st group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex: `\d_(.*$)`

\d stands for one digit

_ stands for underscore

() stands for group

.*$ stands for "all till the end of line"

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str= "pot_8_Jack_Furleng_Derik";
     // name starts after number and _
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+_");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    int index = -1;
    // find the index of name
    if(m.find())
    index =  m.start()+2;

    str=  str.substring(index);
    System.out.print(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Reflection to get the actual name of the variable as seen 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable)
You can further break that down with Regex, as also mentioned